# slow reception of BLE packets on iPhone from nRF52 ARM

Tags: ios, performance, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

I built a custom ARM device based on the nRF52 SOC that handles BLE 5.  I wrote a custom app in SWIFT/X-Code/IB using Core Bluetooth framework and am unable to stream data from the ARM device any faster than about 12 kbs.  Using packet sniffers I can see that the ARM device sent all of the packets in realtime, but the iPhone doesn't read them any faster than a few times per second.  On rare occasion the iPhone reads everything quickly. The Bluetooth connection negotiates to a 12-24 ms latency. I am using Nordic nRF52 SDK version 16. The iPhone is not connected to any other BLE devices at the time.

Has anyone else had this issue?  If it is helpful, I can post the code used on the ARM device and the XCode code.

Comment: Are you using an  L2Cap channel?

Comment: After looking deeper it looks like I am using GATT (default in Nordic SDK)

Comment: For high data rate transfer on BLE you will need to use an L2Cap channel.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The ARM device sends all the packets quickly in realtime; the iPhone simply processes them slowly.  Would changing to L2Cap affect how the iPhone processes incoming data?

Comment: Yes, an L2Cap channel is a stream connection designed to transfer large amounts of data more quickly. It has less overhead that GATT and doesn't have the same size limitations.

Answer (score 0):

As your using the nordic board there are several things to check to "speed up the process". Firstly I assume you are sending via notifications. Secondly you need to know what forms your data rate. They are:

- Number of bits per notification
- Connection interval
- Events per connection interval
- Data communication type

Also you can queue up-several packets to store until they are sent via the notification(filling a buffer).

So some useful settings. First and foremost maximise the data you are sending per packet. E.g if you are sending 10 bytes of data send more, this will be limited to the maximum data size on the nordic board (247). Then increase the GAP length. So some settings I recommend to start are:

- Go to sdk_config.h
- Change NRF_SDH_BLE_GAP_EVENT_LENGTH to 400(think the default is 6)
- Increase the MTU size to 247

Then run on the board, you will probably get an error saying change ram and start location. This will be printed to a terminal. You can do this by going:

- Project
- Options
- Common
- Press up arrow till under project
- Linker
- Section placement macros.

From there change your ram start and allocation variables to what is printed in the terminal / putty / debugger. Also not sure about the APIs for iphone apps but android has a function to set the bluetooth hardware into high power mode, this increased my throughput whilst transferring data, just disable it after data transfer. The APIs your using may have a similar function.

For reference code there is an example called maximum_throughput in the sdk, this should be a good reference point.

Comment: thank you for your detailed reponse.  I tried changing the event length to 400 and the code crashed but did not provide a new memory start address.  I am still thinking this is on the receiving end- when I sniff for packets sent from the nRF52 device, they all are sent quickly and in real time.  The problem seems to be at the iPhone end where it slowly receives and decodes the packets.  I have heard the the iPhone slows Bluetooth communication for non-standard connections and I am wondering if I am victim to that.

Comment: Thats a shame, if you think it could be the nordic side look at the aforementioned example there are a bunch of settings to change that you could use. If its the iphone side it maybe it can not decode the packets fast enough. One possible idea for this is to process the data after the data is received. What i mean by this is store the data raw from the notification then, process it after all the data is received. That way less processing is happening when the data is being transfered.